# Fragment will be blank after minimizing app for some time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

In an android app I have some fragments which loads images from web on starting the app.When i start app everything will work fine, even when i minimize and suddenly maximize the app it will work fine.But if i minimize the app for more than half an hour and then if i maximize the app it wont load any images from web in the fragment.How do i overcome this and manage to load images even after resuming the app?

```
 public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements RecyclerViewOnClickListenerHack {

    protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    protected List<Data> mList;
    protected Activity mActivity;
    protected ProgressBar mPbLoad;



    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = activity;
    }


      @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pics, container, false);

        mList = new ArrayList<>();
        mPbLoad = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pbar_load);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyle_list);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);


                LinearLayoutManager linear = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();


                if (mList.size() == linear.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() + 1
                        && (mSwipeRefreshLayout == null || !mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())) {
      //Using Volley              NetworkConnection.getInstance(getActivity()).execute(FirstFragment.this, FirstFragment.class.getName());

                }


            }
        });
        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewTouchListener(getActivity(), mRecyclerView, this));

        LinearLayoutManager linear = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linear.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linear);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {

            mList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("mList");
            if( mList == null || mList.size() == 0 ){

                 NetworkConnection.getInstance(getActivity()).execute(this, FirstFragment.class.getName());

            }
        }
        else{ 
               NetworkConnection.getInstance(getActivity()).execute(this, FirstFragment.class.getName());

                    }
    }




    @Override
    public void onClickListener(View view, int position) {
    //some piece of code
    }


    @Override
    public void onLongPressClickListener(View view, int position) {
       }


    private static class RecyclerViewTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
        //some piece of code
    }



    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        outState.putParcelableArrayList("mList", (ArrayList<Movie>) mList);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        NetworkConnection.getInstance(getActivity()).getRequestQueue().cancelAll(FirstFragment.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }


@Override
public WrapToNetwork doBefore() {
    mPbLoad.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );

    if( Utility.verifyConnection(getActivity()) ){
        Data data = new Data();
        data.setCat(0);

        if( mList != null && mList.size() > 0 ){
            data.setId( mSwipeRefreshLayout != null && mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing() ? mList.get(0).getId() : mList.get(mList.size() - 1).getId() );
        }

        return( new WrapToNetwork(data, "get-data", (mSwipeRefreshLayout != null && mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) ) );
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void doAfter(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    mPbLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if( jsonArray != null ){
        MyAdapter adapter = (MyAdapter) mRecyclerView.getAdapter();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        int auxPosition = 0, position;

        if( mSwipeRefreshLayout != null && mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing() ){
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            auxPosition = 1;
        }

        try{
            for(int i = 0, j = jsonArray.length(); i < j; i++){
                Data data = gson.fromJson( jsonArray.getJSONObject( i ).toString(), Data.class );
                position = auxPosition == 0 ? mList.size() : 0;
                adapter.addListItem(data, position);

                if( auxPosition == 1 ){
                    mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerView, null, position);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            Log.i(TAG, "doAfter(): "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else{

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Try Later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}


}
```

Comment: Did you try it with different devices? Does all of them do the same? Some phones freeze the process, others kill the app, etc etc

Comment: normal behaviour ... process is getting killed and obviously `mList` is empty ... there is no way to fix it as this code is FUBAR  ...

Comment: @MkiiSoft Yeah this happens with all the devices

Comment: I think this question is hard to answer without doing some tests. Do you receive any errors in logcat?

An easy (but maybe not the prettiest) solution to your problem is to reload the data by overriding onResume in your activity.

Comment: @Selvin : Did you check onSaveInstanceState() in his code?

Comment: @lamachine do you know when it is called? Do you even know fragment life-cycle? Did you find out where he is setting mList in his code other then empty list? This code is written by someone who doesn't know android's basics

Comment: @Prince John If i reload the data in onResume then wont it load data twice when the app starts?

Comment: @Selvin Pointing it out nicely in your first comment is the right way and the nice way. Calling someone's code - who is asking for help - foobar is not.

Comment: Updated my code.Thank you everyone

Comment: @RamachandraBhagwat you can prevent this by initiating a boolean to false and then setting it to true in your fragment, before you load the data in onResume, check the boolean. This will prevent it from loading twice when your application starts.

Comment: @Prince John Yeah i shall try.Thank you.